# How to trace why a PHP script fails to write to a database?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm sorry but I am on a test server (which I do not own), and I am trying to develop my site. This bit of code should be taking the $_POST information and inserting it into a mysql db. (I know its not secure, I'm just trying this for testing purposes).

When I try to display an error, its so vague and says that something is wrong with a quotation mark on line one, there isn't even a quotation mark on line one.

```
<?php

include "includes/connect.php";

session_start();

if($_SESSION['username'] != null) {
    if($_POST['title'] != null){

        $query = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO posts (id, title, date,     body, author) VALUE (null, '" . $_POST['title'] . "', now(), '" . $_POST['body']     . "', '" . $_POST['author'] . "'");



    }else{
        echo "Unauthorized";
    }
}else {

    echo "Unauthorized";
}

?>
```

Comment: Check the `includes/connect.php` file whether all the details entered are correct

Comment: The code which you've shared is that a full code of partial one? Because PHP starting tag is missing from the code.

Comment: Yeah, I double checked. The connect file even has error output if it fails...I'm 100% sure that its not in there. I have other files that use the connect and they don't have bugs. Thanks though

Comment: @mi6crazyheart its the full code...I just forgot to paste the starting tag sorry but its in the actual file.

Comment: Can you post the exact error message whatever you are getting.

Comment: once I put the parenthesis around the include, I get no errors, but my mysql database has not been updated...

Comment: Would you `echo` the SQL line and paste it here?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you wrote **VALUE** instead of **VALUES**.

Also, you should break up your code and use a bit of debugging:

```
extract($_POST); // Doing this will break up your array keys into variables.

$sql   =  "INSERT INTO posts (id, title, date,body, author) VALUES (null, '". $title ."', NOW(), '".$body. "', '". $author."')";

$query =  mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error());
```

Comment: I have thought of that, and tried VALUES. It doesn't change the errors though :(

Answer (score 0):

> Change of the syntax of Include shall make a trick for you.

Replace

```
include "includes/connect.php";
```

With

```
include ("includes/connect.php");
```

Comment: Or you put `error_reporting(E_ALL)` at the top of the file and check your Error in the codes.

Comment: Have you changed the include file as how i suggested

Comment: Try this `$query = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO posts (`title`,`date`,`body`,`author`) VALUE ('".$_POST['title']."',NOW(),'".$_POST['body']."','".$_POST['author']."'");`

Comment: <?php
//This is where the code for connecting to the mysql database is located!

//Connection Information
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_user = "superdupersecretuser";
$db_pass = "superdupersecretpassword";
$db_name = "superdupersecretusername";

//Connect to database
$conn = mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass,$db_name);

//Check if connection is successfull
if(!$conn){
 die("I'm sorry, but there was an error. <br />" . mysqli_connect_error());
}

Comment: Try connectivity using `$conn = new mysqli($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass,$db_name);`

Comment: At last you have to check the DB is connected or not. Since other all are correct as per suggestions..

Comment: The brackets in the `include` call won't make a difference here. In general the call is preferred without brackets these days, unless you need to call it in a function context (i.e. to return a value).

Answer (score 0):

Try fixing your query, instead of VALUE it should be VALUES. 
check out this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Just Replace you code with this one:

```
<?php
include "includes/connect.php";

session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['username']) and ($_SESSION['username'] != null )) {
    if(isset($_POST['title']) and ($_POST['title'] != null )) {

        $query = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO posts (`id`, `title`, `date`, `body`, `author`) VALUES (Null, '".$_POST['title']."', now(), '".$_POST['body']."', '".$_POST['author']."'") or die(mysqli_error($conn));



    }else{
        echo "Unauthorized";
    }
}else {

    echo "Unauthorized";
}

?>
```

Comment: I did, it outputs this error: 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: then check it is connected with database or not, check your mysqli_connect query

Answer (score 0):

This will work properly -

```
<?php
session_start();
include "includes/connect.php";

if(isset($_SESSION['username']) && !empty($_SESSION['username'])) {

    if(isset($_POST['title']) && !empty($_POST['title'])) {

        $query = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO posts (`id`, `title`, `date`, `body`, `author`) VALUES (Null, '".$_POST['title']."', now(), '".$_POST['body']."', '".$_POST['author']."'") or die(mysqli_error($conn));

        $result =  mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    }else{
        echo "Unauthorized";
    }
}else {

    echo "Unauthorized";
}
?>
```